# Net Core API with API Key and JWT token

Tags: api, asp.net-core, api-key, jwt

I have a .Net Core API with some endpoints needing a JWT authorization while the others an API Key authorization. I'm implementing an attribute for API Key methods while using Authorize on the methods that require JWT token after configuring JWT authentication in the startup.cs. Am I on the right track? I'm new to .Net Core and API and appreciate any help.

Comment: show some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's Correct, As you Know The startup class configures the request pipeline of the application and how all requests are handled

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using WebApi.Helpers;
using WebApi.Services;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;

namespace WebApi
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors();
            services.AddControllers();

            // configure strongly typed settings objects
            var appSettingsSection = Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings");
            services.Configure<AppSettings>(appSettingsSection);

            // configure jwt authentication
            var appSettings = appSettingsSection.Get<AppSettings>();
            var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(appSettings.Secret);
            services.AddAuthentication(x =>
            {
                x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(x =>
            {
                x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                x.SaveToken = true;
                x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false
                };
            });

            // configure DI for application services
            services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseRouting();

            // global cors policy
            app.UseCors(x => x
                .AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader());

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @hesam akbari. That's basically what I put in the startup.cs. I used Authorize attribute for methods that require JWT token and the API key filter for the ones that require API key. However when I test it in swagger, the ones that require JWT still ask for API key. Maybe it's my swagger setting?